# Accuracy goes low with attention layer

Tags: lstm, attention-mechanism

Below is code 1 which is not using Attention layer :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(maxlen,)))
model.add(Embedding(max_features, embed_size))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(10)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3, batch_size=64)
```

The output is (Accuracy=98.22%):

```
Epoch 1/3
164/164 [==============================] - 49s 282ms/step - loss: 0.3407 - accuracy: 0.9317 - val_loss: 0.1843 - val_accuracy: 0.9392
Epoch 2/3
164/164 [==============================] - 46s 278ms/step - loss: 0.1579 - accuracy: 0.9329 - val_loss: 0.1719 - val_accuracy: 0.9403
Epoch 3/3
164/164 [==============================] - 46s 282ms/step - loss: 0.0727 - accuracy: 0.9822 - val_loss: 0.2001 - val_accuracy: 0.9227
```

Below is code with Attention layer:

```
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention
modelAtt = Sequential()
modelAtt.add(Input(shape=(maxlen,)))
modelAtt.add(Embedding(max_features, embed_size, input_length=maxlen))
modelAtt.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)))
modelAtt.add(SeqSelfAttention())
modelAtt.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
modelAtt.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(modelAtt.summary())

modelAtt.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3, batch_size=64)
```

The output is (Accuracy=97.45%):

```
Epoch 1/3
164/164 [==============================] - 68s 395ms/step - loss: 0.3464 - accuracy: 0.8997 - val_loss: 0.1741 - val_accuracy: 0.9418
Epoch 2/3
164/164 [==============================] - 64s 391ms/step - loss: 0.1451 - accuracy: 0.9424 - val_loss: 0.1647 - val_accuracy: 0.9430
Epoch 3/3
164/164 [==============================] - 64s 391ms/step - loss: 0.0773 - accuracy: 0.9745 - val_loss: 0.1898 - val_accuracy: 0.9337
```

The data is quora questions - [Quora Dataset on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-insincere-questions-classification/data)

I have tried reducing the number of LSTM layers to avoid overfitting.
What is causing the accuracy to go low when using attention?

Comment: why do you think attention should increase the accuracy in the first place?

Comment: Isn't it invented for the same? Doesn't it allow model to pay attention to more relevant terms, causing improved understanding?

Comment: This can be so only if attention is focused on the important right parts (if indeed there are such). Else it is almost effectiveless

Comment: see this as well https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/11/9/3883